# Where went the Google Photos album "Hangouts"?

Tags: google-hangouts, google-photos

For some time you could see pictures someone sent you via Hangouts in an album called "Hangouts". This vanished somehow.

When you open a picture from Hangouts on the Computer, you can still see in the URL that there is some kind of album. The URL is in the form `https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/albums/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` and you can even browse this album.

How can I get to this album from Google Plus or Google Photos?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Short answer<sup>1</sup>

Go to https://get.google.com/albumarchive/
There you will found a album named Photos from Hangouts
[image]

## Long answer

When you click a photo in the Hangout history you will be sent to an URL that looks like
https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/albums/string-1?pid=string-2&oid=string-3. To be taken to the album just delete ? and all the characters to the right of it. The resulting URL will look like this:

https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/albums/string-1

The photos owned by the user uploaded through Hangouts conversation can't be seen from Google Photos (http://photos.google.com), only on the owner Google Album Archive.

For each Hangout used to share a photo will be an album called "Hangout: Your Friend Name or email address ● Your Name" or "Hangout: Group name" on the photo sender account. It could be viewable by both users using the URL trick mentioned in the "Short answer" section.

## References

- [Google Hangouts Photo Sharing, Powered by Picasa Web](http://googlesystem.blogspot.mx/2015/07/google-hangouts-photo-sharing-powered.html)
- [Share and delete your photos](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3115410?hl=en)

## Update Notes

<sup>1</sup> Picasa Web Albums was deprecated on 2016. On August 2016 Google launched Google Album Archive where users could access their photos that used to be accessible through Picasa Web Albums (reference: http://googlephotos.blogspot.com/2016/02/moving-on-from-picasa.html)

Comment: Looks like the Picasa Web Albums only includes photes shared /by me/ not pictures shared /with me/. The url trick still works though showing an album on G+ with all the pictures.

Comment: @rumpel: Thanks. I updated the answer.

Comment: @rumpel not anymore...

Comment: I wonder how this will work as G+ is deprecated.

Comment: @DustinGraham Google Hangouts dependency on G+ Albums was removed sometime ago, so Hangouts albums will not be affected by the G+ shutdown

Answer (score 2):

Update for 2020 - I still could not find anyway to get all shared images. I made a small python script that downloads everything from chat history.

You can check it out in [GitHub](https://github.com/KristianKalm/HangoutsDownloader)

Answer (score 1):

It appears this has been deprecated. If you want to download all of the images that have ever been shared with you over hangouts, you need to use Google Takeout.

- Visit https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout
- Deselect all
- Select Hangouts
- Hit the download button

Google will send you a .zip link with all of the images.

Answer (score 1):

Using Linux commands `jq` and `curl` on `Hangouts.json` from [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout):

```
jq -r '.conversations[].events[].chat_message.message_content.attachment[]?.embed_item.plus_photo.url' Hangouts.json > urls.txt
while read -r l; do curl -O "$l"; done < urls.txt
```

This method will download all images shared to you and by you.

Comment: For the latest iteration (Google Chat) you need to download the Chat zip from Takeout as above, find the corresponding Groups/ directory then use this `jq` command: `jq -r '.messages[].annotations[]?.url_metadata.image_url' messages.json > urls.txt` and this `bash` loop: `export i=1; while read -r l; do export i=$(($i+1)); curl -L -o $i.jpg "$l"; done < urls.txt` - the filnames aren't usable so it numbers the images `1.jpg` and upwards. Not all items with URLs are images and those are saved as empty files.

Answer (score 0):

**Viewing Photos shared with you**

On https://get.google.com/albumarchive/ you can only see photos that were shared **by you**. To see the album of pictures shared **with you** by a specific person, perform the following steps:

1. Navigate to the Person’s G+ Profile (by clicking on the person’s icon in Hangouts)
2. Select "About" button in the profile’s header
3. Scroll down to "You & Person" and click "See all photos"
4. Select the "Photos from Hangouts" album

Comment: I don't have "See all photos" :(